# Connecting Wear OS emulator with a physical android device

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, wear-os, android-virtual-device

I am trying to connect a wearable emulator with 4.4 Android phone following the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating#creating-or-updating-a-project), however when i forward adb using the command `adb -d forward tcp:5601 tcp:5601` nothing happens, and the screen gets stuck [on this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aF3MN.png), clicking on "skip and finish setup" does nothing [as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mMo4.png).
i tried:

1. changing the USB port
2. restarting both devices (emulator and phone)
3. using `adb forward tcp:4444 localabstract:/adb-hub; adb connect localhost:4444`
4. making sure i am using the correct SDK file

Does anyone know what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. You should turn on developer mode in your Wear OS emulator
2. The same in the physical device (developer mode I mean)
3. In your physical device, download Wear OS by Google in the Google Play market
4. Using "adb -d forward tcp:5601 tcp:5601"
5. To connect with your Wear OS

Comment: thank you for your answer.
I have done all the above already but for some reason the wear os app freezes at the screenshot i previously showed in post

Comment: first of all, When you use the command "adb -d forward tcp:5601 tcp:5601", do you recieve a response message "5601"? and second, did you do point the way to your "Users\Android\SDK\platform-tools\adb" ? third one, do you plug usb cable in order to launch your app ine in your physical device?

Comment: yes i did get 5601, and yes i located the SDK file correctly and plugged the phone physically. big chance the problem is with wear os app on the phone.